# HRESULT: 0x800A03EC VB

Tags: vb.net, excel

```
oBook.Worksheets(1).Range("$D$1:$D$4000").AutoFilter(Field:=4, Criteria:="#N/A")
```

Running the code I get the following error:
An unhandled exception of type `'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

After looking around the internet and trying to get this to work, I am struggling to find answers.

I would like the code to filter out all of the #N/A entries in Column D.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Field:=4` for a one column range. The `Field` parameter is an index into the range's columns, not the actual column number (eg. 4 for col D). Also the second parameter is `Criteria1` and not `Criteria`:

```
oBook.Worksheets(1).Range("$D$1:$D$4000").AutoFilter(Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>#N/A")
```

Comment: Thankyou for that input, but upon changing the code to what you put and running it again, I receive the same error

Comment: This wouldn't give the error described in the question though. I think the problem is deeper.

Comment: See my edit above. Also, this is obviously not VBA in Excel, so you probably should have added different tags. ;)

Comment: @Rory Okok, we are getting somewhere! It just shows the #N/A and I want it to filter out the #N/A's and show the rest